# Prevent Emacs from linebreaking in TeX inline math

Tags: emacs, auctex, math-mode

I use Emacs in combination with AUCTeX to edit manuscripts with a lot of inline maths using `$`. When automatic filling (e.g., with <kbd>M-q</kbd>), Emacs often breaks these inline math environments at positions which disturbs the fluency of reading (e.g., in subscripts or the like).

Is there a way to tell Emacs to prefer putting the whole `$…$` environment in a new line if that would prevent breaking? More specifically, if breaking in maths would occur, the whole environment should be moved to a new line which should not be broken apart.

An example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
```

should result in

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-to-list 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'texmathp)))
```

Place it in your `.emacs` and restart emacs.

Comment: Thanks, that's close! It's nice that it gathers short math environments spread over multiple lines. This comes at the cost, however, that very long lines cannot be broken _explicitely_ (I mean that the explicit breaks are deleted when pressing `M-q`). Do you know how to incorporate this. (It's tricky though; I even cannot state it more precisely in a concise way.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "explicit breaks". If you just mean positions of the text where you pressed `RET`, well, there's no way of distinguishing those from the automatic line breaks done by the emacs filling functions. You could, however, add the comment symbol `%` at the end of a line to try to prevent that line break from being changed by `M-q`.

Comment: What I mean is that if long math (longer than one line) already is on a seperate line and broken (by whomsoever), then I do not want to pull Emacs subsequent lines up (i.e., _don't remove_ a linebreak if that would lead to too long a line). I'm already using `%` but it is not very convenient.

Comment: I think I understand. However, what you want does not seem possible using the `fill-nobreak-predicate` variable. Before even calling the functions from this list, `M-q` already collapses the whole paragraph to a single line, making it impossible to figure out where the previous line breaks occurred.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. There may be a different solution, not using `fill-nobreak-predicate`, though…

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'my-latex-fill-nobreak)))
```

and then define a function `my-latex-fill-nobreak` which returns non-nil if you're inside a short math environment, e.g. something like:

```
(defun my-latex-fill-nobreak ()
  (save-excursion
    (when (search-backward "$" (- (point) 20) t)
      ;; We found a nearby $.  Now let's see if it's an opening $
      ;; rather than a closing one.  Using font-lock properties is
      ;; a hack, but it might be good enough.  Apparently (texmathp)
      ;; could be a better choice.
      (eq (get-text-property (point) 'face) 'font-latex-math-face))))
```

Comment: You might use `texmathp` to detect whether point is in math mode.

Comment: I tried to add this to ~/.emacs but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Probably because of the unquoted $ in the regexp search.  I changed it to use a non-regexp search instead, which might fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's nice that it puts long maths onto its own line. There's an issue with that, however, as it seems to erroneously put the last part (including the closing `$`) to the next line. What's more, can you explain where the threshold comes from (trial-and-error gave me something around 47 but I don't see where this comes from).